# Effectivity, Android switch or click listener for each button

Tags: android, performance, button

I cant found the topic, perhaps someone can teach me some about android effectivity when the topis is about onclicklistener for buttons.

Lets say I got 10 buttons on a page (just an example now)
What's the best thing to do?

1. A switch that switch id for the buttons?
2. A onClickListener for each button?

What method is the faster one, and why?
Is there any different at all?

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to **go with 1st option: A switch that switch id for the butttons.**

As per my experience, i would suggest you to assign android:onClick attribute with same value, say for example: android:onClick="btnClicker"

And now you have to implement the same method inside the activity class as:

```
public void btnClicker(View v)
{
   switch(v.getId())
   { 
    case R.id.btn1:
         break;

    case R.id.btn2:
         break;

    case R.id.btn3:
         break;
   }
}
```

**About 2nd option:**
I don't prefer it because it increase number of code lines because just think you are having 10 buttons and you assign separate click listener for each buttons. And now compare it with the above 1st option, you will realize it.

So i would suggest you to go with 1st option i have suggested with example above, main reason is it decrease number of code lines and better readability of code.

**Why there is better readability in 1st option i have suggested above?**

Because you know you just have to check this particular function only for the code for every buttons, because everything is here inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

I would be surprised if there is any significant difference. I would go with #2 because I think it leads to clearer code.

Answer (score 0):

I think answer 1 is effectivity. 
because create object will slow down the app.
and the RAM limit in mobile phone should be considered.