# Button navigate to different activities based on XML value

Tags: android

I have multiple buttons on an activity that are dynamically created at runtime. I want to do something like this:

```
<Button
    ....
    myProp="myValue">
```

And then in the event for the button I can get `myValue` and decide where to navigate. How should I go about storing this information?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I already know how to navigate to the correct activity based on `myValue`, I just need a way to store and retrieve it.

Comment: Please check if the below link helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412478/effectivity-android-switch-or-click-listener-for-each-button

Comment: There are about 40 different activities that could possibly be linked to (they all display text content)... it would be a pain to keep track of an ID for each one and what each ID links to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `View` objects have a `tag` property, which can store any object you want. 
In [Android `View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) reference:

> Tags
>
> Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially
>   an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They
>   are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in
>   the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate
>   structure.

So you could do this:

```
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:tag="myProp"/>
```

And then, programmatically do the following:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
String myButtonTag = (String) myButton.getTag();
```

Didn't check if the code above works, but give it a try.

Hope it helps!